# How to configure Tomcat plugin profile in Gradle

Tags: maven, tomcat, gradle, profile

I had a maven project where am using the maven tomcat plugin to run it. I have converted it to gradle automatically using the command gradle init. So all my pom.xml files are converted to guild.gradle files.

**The problem is :**   with the new build.gradle file i don't see my tomcat plugin so i can't execute the command `gradle tomcatRun`.

**What i want :** How can i use the same configuration of my plugin used in maven in gradle? Why it's not been converted automatically?

Here is my tomcat plugin declared in the pom.xml

```
   <profile>
            <id>tomcat7</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <serverXml>${project.build.directory}/config/tomcat-config/${ds.vendor}/server.xml
                            </serverXml>
                            <tomcatUsers>${project.build.directory}/config/tomcat-config/tomcat-users.xml</tomcatUsers>
                            <configurationDir>${project.build.directory}/config/tomcat-config</configurationDir>
                            <warDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</warDirectory>
                            <port>${tomcat.http.local.port}</port>
                            <path>/${url.contextPath}</path>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>myProject.thirdparty.oracle</groupId>
                                <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                                <version>${oracle.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>myproject.thirdparty.oracle</groupId>
                                <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
                                <version>${oracle.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>myProject.thirdparty.microsoft-sqlserver</groupId>
                                <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
                                <version>4.1</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

        </profile>
```

And this is my build.gradle file generated automatically:

```
 apply plugin: 'war'
 jar.enabled = true
 description = 'My Project'

  dependencies {
    compile project(':myProject-core')
    compile(group: 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl', name: 'jstl-api', version:'1.2') {
    exclude(module: 'servlet-api')
    } 
    compile group: 'taglibs', name: 'standard', version:'1.1.2'
    compile project(':myProject-core-ws')
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version:'3.1.0'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', name: 'jsp-api', version:'2.2'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.el', name: 'el-api', version:'2.2'

 }

 task packageTests(type: Jar) {
   from sourceSets.test.output
   classifier = 'tests'
 }
 artifacts.archives packageTests

 }
```